# Is EIN sufficient to open a business bank checkin account for LLC?

Tags: limited-liability-company, checking-account, ein

I am a non US citizen living overseas. I had formed a LLC in WY using state agent and was able to get EIN number through FSS-4 form.
Now that I have heard, bank requires physical visit of owner to open a bank account, I am planing to visit states for a week.
My question is that wouuld I be able to open a business checkin account with the help of EIN number that I have got? As you may know that I don't have SSN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a question your financial institution would be best suited to answer, as there may be specific requirements from bank to bank and they may vary depending on what type of business you're in (i.e. if you're in an industry requiring licensing, they may want to see a license.) Also, you mention hearing that the bank will require you to appear in person, that's also going to vary from bank to bank - some offer online-only accounts and do not require customers to appear in person.

That variation aside, we can speak in general terms. A bank will need to identify the business. Banks will want to see the EIN as proof of identity (and because they need it for certain reporting requirements with the government), and they'll want to see your articles of incorporation and other legal documentation as proof of the business structure.

They'll also need to identify you, in order to tie you to the account, and also again in order to fulfill reporting/identity requirements with the government. Since you do not have an SSN, the bank may accept your foreign passport and/or other forms of ID, or you can apply for an ITIN in place of the SSN.